# How to get all of data if tags with a lots of nested?

Tags: scrapy

I try to get first day movie data(today is 8/25), and find the href from website is

`https://www.vscinemas.com.tw/vsweb/theater/detail.aspx?id=16#movieTime-1508017172`

I want to get all of the movie data (name, gradle, time, type...etc), for example:

```
FAST AND FURIOUS 9
childview
數位
['11:30', '12:45', '14:25', '15:30', '17:15', '18:15', '20:00', '21:00', '22:45', '23:45']

1
IMAX
['12:00', '16:45', '21:30']

2
['GC 數位']
['13:00', '16:10', '18:00', '20:50', '23:35']
```

But I the website tags rule, if some movies have multiple types like IMAX 4DX, it will nested another `<div class="movieDay" />`, and other movies data will under the `<div />`, of course, if still has another multiple types of movies, it will nested again!

When I write until inThreeNode, I found it is not right, because I have to check and nested over and over again. It must have some ways to check the rule and write the more clear code, but I have no idea how to achieve it.

Here is my spider, any helps would be appreciated.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import sys
import time

class TesttwoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'testtwo'
    allowed_domains = ['www.vscinemas.com.tw/vsweb/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vscinemas.com.tw/vsweb/theater/detail.aspx?id=16']

    # print(sys.path)

    # use selenium
    # options = Options()
    # options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    
    # chrome = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/motogod19/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
    # chrome.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

    def parse(self, response):
        print('************ Start parse ************')
        # childview one of movie types
        # teenager one of movie types

        firstHtmlNodes = response.xpath('//div[@class="theaterTime"]/article[@id="movieTime-1508017172"]')
        for firstHtmlNode in firstHtmlNodes:
            cnName = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./h2/text()').extract()

            print('Check length')
            print(len(cnName))

            getFistFloorEnNameLength = len(cnName)
            for index in range(len(cnName)):
                movieName = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./h2[{}]/text()'.format(index+1)).extract_first()
                movieGradle = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./h1[{}]/span/@class'.format(index+1)).extract_first()
                movieType = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./div[{}]/h4/text()'.format(index+1)).extract_first()
                movieTime = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./div[{}]/ul/li/a/text()'.format(index+1)).extract()
                print(movieName)
                print(movieGradle)
                print(movieType)
                print(movieTime)
                # lats one check <div class="movieDay" /> exists or not
                if getFistFloorEnNameLength == index + 1:
                    nextNode = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./div[{}]/div[1]'.format(index+1))
                    if len(nextNode) != 0:
                        movieType = nextNode.xpath('./h4/text()').extract_first()
                        movieTime = nextNode.xpath('./ul/li/a/text()').extract()
                        print('1')
                        print(movieType)
                        print(movieTime)
                        
                        inTwoNode = nextNode.xpath('./div[1]')

                        if len(inTwoNode) != 0:
                            movieType = inTwoNode.xpath('./h4/text()').extract()
                            movieTime = inTwoNode.xpath('./ul/li/a/text()').extract()
                            print('2')
                            print(movieType)
                            print(movieTime)
                            # I stop here, because I have to check and nested over and over again.
                            inThreeNode = inTwoNode.xpath('./h2/text()')

                        else:
                            movieName = firstHtmlNode.xpath('./div[{}]/h2/text()'.format(index+1))
                            print('3')
                            print(movieName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML code is broken on this page (`<div class="movieDay"` tags are not properly closed). You can try to edit HTML and close above tags *manually* (I used regular expression):

```
import re
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class TesttwoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = '68916451'
    allowed_domains = ['www.vscinemas.com.tw/vsweb/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vscinemas.com.tw/vsweb/theater/detail.aspx?id=16']

    # print(sys.path)

    # use selenium
    # options = Options()
    # options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    
    # chrome = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/motogod19/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
    # chrome.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

    def parse(self, response):
        content = response.text
        content = re.sub(r'</ul>\s*(</?div)', r'</ul>\n</div>\1', content)
        # with open('Samples/68916451.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #     f.write(content)
        response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, body=content, encoding='utf-8')

        for movie_day in response.xpath('//article[last()]//div[@class="movieDay"]'):
            movie_title = movie_day.xpath('./preceding-sibling::h2[1]/text()').get()
            movie_type = movie_day.xpath('./h4/text()').get()
            movie_time = movie_day.xpath('./ul/li/a/text()').getall()
            yield {
                'Title': movie_title,
                'Type': movie_type,
                'Time': movie_time
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I don't even know I can edit the `Html`, I try your code and I can get all of the data.
But what the code meaning `re.sub(r'</ul>\s*(</?div)', r'</ul>\n</div>\1', content)` and the yield result is not correct completely, movie_title is not compare the correct movie_time

Comment: @Morton  My regular expression adds closing `div` tag between `</ul>` and `div` tags.

Comment: Thanks for response, can I know one more thing why movie time is not correct, it looks like get second day movie time, even I edit the article like `response.xpath('//article[@id="movieTime791500081"]//div[@class="movieDay"]'):` still won't work.